# migrate from sql server 2012 to sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have been looking for the information since yesterday and could not find anything...
I have sharepoint 2012 fundation and my SQL Server 2010 Evaluation is short of space (we already used 10GB), however I have SQL Server 2008 R2 license.

Question:

- Is it possible to migrate my SQL Server 2012 sharepoint database to
  SQL Server 2008? Will the new database be compatible with my sharepoint?
- could you please send me a link with the
  instructions?

thank you very much

Comment: Never heard of Sql Server 2010. Could you try "SELECT @@version" within SSMS to give us the proper version? My bet would be on 2008R2.

Comment: sorry @KookieMonster I ment SQL Server 2012... my mistake

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a tool such as Redgate SQL Data Compare. I have had to do this in the past and it has worked well. First you run a schema compare to create an empty database in the 2008 server and then run data compare to pump the data in.

There are other vendors offering similar tools and I believe the new Visual Studio also has something like this. The Redgate offering does give you a two week trial which may be good if you only need it for a one of migration.

Click [here](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-developer-bundle/) for the trial.

Comment: Suggesting purchasing software as the 'only' way to do something, when it isn't, is misleading...

Comment: Sometimes the pressure is so high that purchasing is the way out

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from SQL Server 2012 to 2008 is not only possible, it can be done entirely within SSMS, with no need to purchase additional software.

You'll need to run the [Generate Scripts](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/) wizard, target Server Version SQL Server 2008 and then run the scripts generated to import all the data to your new database.

With larger databases, it may be a bit of a lengthy task, so script the minimal amount of data that you'll actually need

Comment: will that script create all users, permissions, etc on my new db instance?